# Can I remap a topic from rosrun

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can I remap a topic from rosrun or must I set up a launch file.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/116061/can-i-remap-a-topic-from-rosrun/) by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on ROS Answers with karma: 713 on 2014-01-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-01-09**:
Please don't close any questions unless there is a need to do so. If you find a correct answer click the small checkmark to the left. This will signal that a question was answered in the overview.

**Comment by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on 2014-01-09**:
In close drop down there is a item that says " question is answered, right answer accepted". What does this mean in the light of your comment.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-01-09**:
Only that clicking the checkmark is the preferred option to signal that a question was answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As documented on the [Remapping Arguments](http://wiki.ros.org/Remapping%20Arguments) wiki page, you can easily remap arguments using rosrun from the command line (see example there).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-01-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1